# Django -I need to implement drag and drop to upload file

Tags: html, django

I am using django to develop a small project and i want to implement drag and drop to upload file .I have already implemented basic file upload from choose file and it is working fine .
Please help me

I have tried below code for simple file uploading but i need drag and drop and i dont know how to implement the same .

```
{% block content %}
  <div method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="file" name="myfile"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="upload">

{% endblock %}

Views.py

def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage(location="test/uploadedmedia")
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url,"fileupload":"File uploaded successfully"})
    return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

I need file to be dragged and gets uploaded.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Drag @drop</title>
<style>

.dropzone{
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   border:2px dashed #ccc;
   color:#ccc;
   line-height:300px;
   text-align:center;

 }
.dropzone.dragover{
    border-color:#000;
    color:#000;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="upload"></div>
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">Drop files here</div>

<script>
    (function(){
    var dropzone=document.getElementById('dropzone');


    dropzone.ondrop=function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.className='dropzone';

    x=e.dataTransfer.files
    console.log(x)
    };

    dropzone.ondragover=function(){
    this.className='dropzone dragover';
    return false;
    };

    dropzone.ondragleave=function(){
     this.className='dropzone';

     return false;
     };
    }());

</script>
</body>
</html>

{% load static %}
{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile" >
    <button type="submit" id="butto">Upload</button>
  </form>

  {% if uploaded_file_url %}
    <p>File uploaded at: <a href="{{ uploaded_file_url }}">{{ uploaded_file_url }}</a></p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Drag'n'drop has nothing to do with Django, per se. You should search tutorials for javascript drag'n'drop to upload file first and then come back here if you can't make it posting what code you tried.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for helping hand ,I have tried below code but that is still not working out please help me out .

Comment: You shouldn't add it as an answer but edit your question to include the javascript code.

Comment: Tell us also how it behaves with that javascript code. What does it show in the Network tab of your browsers debugging view?

Comment: When i drop file it is displaying filelist in console tab and nothing in network tab.I have below code for dropzone.I just need to call my upload button when the file is dropped.

    dropzone.ondrop=function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.className='dropzone';

    x=e.dataTransfer.files
    console.log(x)

Comment: and just to mention here ,i am able to upload file by using choose file to upload button for which i provided code above .I just need to use the same input type ="file" name="myfile" while implementing drag and drop.

Comment: Good, you have some HTML and javascript code. Could you add important parts (the form html and dropzone js) to the question? I think your dropzone code is just missing the form submit button and adding the files to the form.

Comment: I Have added full JavaScript code and Views.py code .Please help me with the solution.

Comment: Just to add - When i am dropping file in my console tab it is showing properly file details .


FileList {0: File(3748), length: 1}
0: File(3748) {name: "img2.png", lastModified: 1544678696275, lastModifiedDate: Thu Dec 13 2018 10:54:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 3748, …}
length: 1
__proto__: FileList
item: ƒ item()
length: (...)
constructor: ƒ FileList()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "FileList"
get length: ƒ length()
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution -

In your drop zone just add this below code-

```
  var dropzone=document.getElementById('dropzone');

    dropzone.ondrop=function(e){
    fileinput.files=e.dataTransfer.files
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: hi your code is not allowing to drop file please  help